# Grouping objects in array by date with moment.js library

Tags: arrays, loops, momentjs

I am trying to find out the highest number of tweets in a day made by a given user, with the library, moment.js.

Given an array of tweet timestamps, I am able to sort the tweets by username, but I am having trouble grouping the tweets by their common day and then being able to find the highest number for that user.

A sample timestamp would be { "2017-01-03T10:32:51" }.

This is what I'm working with so far:

```
// const times = { timestamp array }
const timesLength = times.length;
const timesAday = [];

for (i = 0; i < timesLength; i++) {
  const compare = (a, b) => {
    let counter = 0;
    const result = moment(a).isSame(b, "day");
    if (result === true) {
      counter++;
    }
    timesAday.push(counter);
  };
  times.forEach((time) => compare);
};
```

Comment: FYI, you never need to compare anything to true or false... if (result === true) can simply be written as if (result).  Likewise if you wanted to check for a false condition it would be if (!result)

Comment: Thank you, yes I realized that was redundant. Any and all help with the rest is appreciated.